# Set ClientCredentials without using a Proxy?

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to set ClientCredentials without using a generated proxy?  I have seen something about using a ChannelFactory, but is it possible to do it without this as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to call a WCF service from a client, you need a proxy (unless you want to hardcode the SOAP request yourself, which isn't something too easy to do, especially if you're dealing with security). The proxy can be created either using one of the tools to generate the proxy (Add Service Reference, svcutil, etc), or by using `ChannelFactory<T>`. If you're using a generated proxy, you'd use the ClientCredentials property of the proxy (inherited from the base class `ClientBase<T>`. If you use the `ChannelFactory<T>`, you'd set them in the `Credentials` property of the channel factory.

Comment: Also, you need to set the credentials before you open the channel.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the sample code:

```
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8888/TestSevice");
WSHttpBinding wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
ChannelFactory<ISomeServiceInterface> iFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISomeServiceInterface>(wsHttpBinding, endpointAddress);

var clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "sudipto";
clientCredentials.UserName.Password = "sudipto";

iFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.RemoveAll<ClientCredentials>();
iFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(clientCredentials);

var isomeService= iFactory.CreateChannel();
isomeService.SomeFunctionToCall("parameterToTheService");
```